# In VisualGDB using the managed component LVGL, I cannot make unless my computer is connected to the internet

Tags: visual-studio, visualgdb, lvgl

In VisualGDB using the managed component LVGL, I cannot make unless my computer is connected to the internet. I do not want any of my code to change based on outside dependencies, so my code must be able to compile completely offline.

If the computer is offline I get the error
"ERROR: Cannot establish a connection to the component registry.  Are you
connected to the internet?"

Here is a FAILED build log:

```html
Removing c:\projects\PowerBridge/build/VisualGDB/Debug...
Reconfiguring project due to missing Makefile...
Running CMake: C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\VisualGDB\CMake\bin\cmake.exe ../../.. -G "Ninja" -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=DEBUG -DCMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM=C:/SysGCC/esp32/tools/ninja/1.10.2/ninja.exe -DESP_PLATFORM=1 -DCCACHE_ENABLE=0 -DIDF_TARGET=esp32
-- Found Git: C:/Program Files/Git/bin/git.exe (found version "2.41.0.windows.3") 
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 12.2.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 12.2.0
-- The ASM compiler identification is GNU
-- Found assembler: C:/SysGCC/esp32/tools/xtensa-esp32-elf/esp-12.2.0_20230208/xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/xtensa-esp32-elf-gcc.exe
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/SysGCC/esp32/tools/xtensa-esp32-elf/esp-12.2.0_20230208/xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/xtensa-esp32-elf-gcc.exe - skipped
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/SysGCC/esp32/tools/xtensa-esp32-elf/esp-12.2.0_20230208/xtensa-esp32-elf/bin/xtensa-esp32-elf-g++.exe - skipped
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Project is not inside a git repository, or git repository has no commits; will not use 'git describe' to determine PROJECT_VER.
-- Building ESP-IDF components for target esp32
-- Checking Python dependencies...
Python requirements are satisfied.
C:\SysGCC\esp32\esp-idf\v5.1\tools\check_python_dependencies.py:12: DeprecationWarning: pkg_resources is deprecated as an API. See https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/pkg_resources.html
  import pkg_resources
Constraint file: C:\Users\admin\.espressif\espidf.constraints.v5.1.txt
Requirement files:
 - C:\SysGCC\esp32\esp-idf\v5.1\tools\requirements\requirements.core.txt
Python being checked: C:\Users\admin\.espressif\python_env\\idf5.1_py3.8_env\Scripts\python.exe
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
CMake Error at C:/SysGCC/esp32/esp-idf/v5.1/tools/cmake/build.cmake:540 (message):
  ERROR: Cannot establish a connection to the component registry.  Are you
  connected to the internet?

Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/SysGCC/esp32/esp-idf/v5.1/tools/cmake/project.cmake:548 (idf_build_process)
  CMakeLists.txt:4 (project)


See also "C:/projects/PowerBridge/build/VisualGDB/Debug/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
Run "C:\SysGCC\esp32\tools\ninja\1.10.2\ninja.exe " in directory "c:\projects\PowerBridge/build/VisualGDB/Debug" on local computer
C:\SysGCC\esp32\tools\ninja\1.10.2\ninja.exe 
ninja: error: loading 'build.ninja': The system cannot find the file specified.


-------------------------------------------------------------
Command exited with code 1
Executable: C:\SysGCC\esp32\tools\ninja\1.10.2\ninja.exe
Arguments: 
Directory: c:\projects\PowerBridge/build/VisualGDB/Debug
Command-line action failed

========== Project Rebuild Summary ==========
    EmbeddedProject1  rebuilt in 00:05
========== Rebuild: 0 Succeeded, 1 Failed, 0 Skipped ==========
```

And here is a SUCCESSFUL build log:

```html
Run "C:\SysGCC\esp32\tools\ninja\1.10.2\ninja.exe " in directory "c:\projects\PowerBridge/build/VisualGDB/Debug" on local computer
C:\SysGCC\esp32\tools\ninja\1.10.2\ninja.exe 
[1/9] Performing build step for 'bootloader'
[1/1] cmd.exe /C "cd /D C:\projects\PowerBridge\build\VisualGDB\Debug\bootloader\esp-idf\esptool_py && python C:/SysGCC/esp32/esp-idf/v5.1/components/partition_table/check_sizes.py --offset 0x8000 bootloader 0x1000 C:/projects/PowerBridge/build/VisualGDB/Debug/bootloader/bootloader.bin"
Bootloader binary size 0x6820 bytes. 0x7e0 bytes (7%) free.
[2/7] Building C object esp-idf/main/CMakeFiles/__idf_main.dir/lvgl_demo_ui.c.obj
[3/7] Linking C static library esp-idf\main\libmain.a
[4/7] Generating ld/sections.ld
[5/7] Linking CXX executable PowerBridge.elf
[6/7] Generating binary image from built executable
esptool.py v4.7.dev1
Creating esp32 image...
Merged 2 ELF sections
Successfully created esp32 image.
Generated C:/projects/PowerBridge/build/VisualGDB/Debug/PowerBridge.bin
[7/7] cmd.exe /C "cd /D C:\projects\PowerBridge\build\VisualGDB\Debug\esp-idf\esptool_py && python C:/SysGCC/esp32/esp-idf/v5.1/components/partition_table/check_sizes.py --offset 0x8000 partition --type app C:/projects/PowerBridge/build/VisualGDB/Debug/partition_table/partition-table.bin C:/projects/PowerBridge/build/VisualGDB/Debug/PowerBridge.bin"
PowerBridge.bin binary size 0x82fa0 bytes. Smallest app partition is 0x100000 bytes. 0x7d060 bytes (49%) free.
------------------- Memory utilization report -------------------
Used DATA_FLASH: 188KB out of 8192KB (2%)
Used INSTR_FLASH: 271KB out of 3264KB (8%)
Used INSTR_RAM: 55KB out of 128KB (43%)
Used DATA_RAM: 44KB out of 320KB (13%)
Used Unknown: 24 bytes

========== Project Build Summary ==========
    EmbeddedProject1  built in 00:07
========== Build: 1 Succeeded, 0 Failed, 0 Skipped ==========
```